# How do I go about writing and pronouncing my name if it has non-english letters

Tags: names, surnames, non-native-english

So I'm soon going to England to study and I'm not quite sure how should I write or pronounce my name in English, which includes Lithuanian letters. I can't imagine anyone spelling my full name correctly, never mind pronouncing it. (It's Mažvydas Janiškevičius)

Do I keep using Lithuanian letters when writing it down/pronouncing it (š instead of s, ž instead of z and č instead of c) or just stick to Latin letters?

I was thinking of just coming up with an English name. If I do, do I need to go through some legal process or just tell my friends to call me by my English name? Also, do I then use that English name when I need to provide it to someone (for example for a reservation at a restaurant, etc.)

Then it still leaves my last name, which if even harder to spell or pronounce than my first name. So yeah, I have no idea how do I go about this.

Comment: Write it as normal but say it out loud so people learn to say it. Your last name does not look too outlandish to me (I am English). I would say Yanishkevishius. The first name is Mazhveedas?  Maybe you are feeling nervous and thinking all English people hate foreigners and don't want to learn their names? Because of all the Brexit stuff? Please. Believe me, we are not all like that. Most are not stupid xenophobes. You will be welcomed. You do not need to change your name to fit in. Please believe me. Don't feel ashamed of who you are. There are people from all over the world here.

Comment: I think the world is slowly becoming more aware of the importance of correct pronunciation.  Your name looks amazing to me.  Are you happy for people to call you "Maz"?  If so, that makes it much easier.  What you can do is write your name as  " Mažvydas (Terry) Janiškevičius"  Insert in brackets the name (or nickname) you wish to be known as.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This isn't really a question about English; you would face the same dilemma for any language or locale with different phonemes and a different alphabet. The short answer is that your name will be often if not always be recorded as if there were no diacritical marks in it, as English does not draw any distinction between accented and non-accented characters in things like sorting. As to pronuncuation, you might adopt a nickname (or English name) that is easier for people to pronounce, a practice common in East Asia.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not a question of the English language or its usage.